# Postgresql helm chart with initdbScripts

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm

I have the following template:

```yaml
image:
  tag: "13"
postgresqlUsername: postgres
postgresqlPassword: "12345678"
postgresqlDatabase: postgres
initdbScripts:
  init: |
    CREATE USER my_app WITH PASSWORD '12345678';
    CREATE DATABASE my_db;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db TO my_app;
```

Running `helm install postgresql bitnami/postgresql -f conf/postgresql/postgresql.yaml`
spins up the deployment with the configmap correctly, but the database "my_db" and the user "my_app" were not created.

I need to use this setup to create multiple databases and users (hence `postgresqlDatabase` is not enough).

How should I work with the `initdbScripts` or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you managed to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

[The script needs a file extension](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql#initialize-a-fresh-instance) so it knows how to run.

Add `.sql` to `init`:

```yaml
image:
  tag: "13"
postgresqlUsername: postgres
postgresqlPassword: "12345678"
postgresqlDatabase: postgres
initdbScripts:
  init.sql: | # <-- Here
    CREATE USER my_app WITH PASSWORD '12345678';
    CREATE DATABASE my_db;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db TO my_app;
```

Comment: Thanks God we have StackOverflow to do our work