# postgres schema does not exist

Tags: postgresql, gitea

I'm totally new to postgres.
On my postgres db I've created a database:

```
CREATE ROLE gitea WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'gitea';
CREATE DATABASE gitea WITH OWNER gitea TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING UTF8 LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8';
CREATE SCHEMA gitea;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA gitea TO gitea;
ALTER USER gitea SET search_path=gitea;
```

Running the gitea application I do get this error, which says schema is not existing. What did I do wrong on the db?

```
2023/06/05 08:12:13 .../cli@v1.22.10/app.go:277:Run() [I] PING DATABASE postgresschema
2023/06/05 08:12:13 models/db/engine.go:190:InitEngineWithMigration() [I] [SQL] SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = $1 [gitea] - 3.310737ms
2023/06/05 08:12:13 ...ations/migrations.go:518:Migrate() [I] [SQL] CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "gitea"."version" ("id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, "version" BIGINT NULL);  [] - 512.953µs
2023/06/05 08:12:13 cmd/migrate.go:40:runMigrate() [F] Failed to initialize ORM engine: migrate: sync: pq: schema "gitea" does not exist
```

Comment: If you're issuing the commands from [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), add a line with [`\c gitea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) before `CREATE SCHEMA gitea;` to connect to the new db and create the schema there. [`select * from information_schema.schemata`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/infoschema-schemata.html) to see schemas available to you in the db you're currently connected to.

Comment: @Zegarek Is it valid to add `\c gitea` to a sql file, which includes the CREATE commands shown in my post?

Comment: Only if it will be interpreted by `psql`. It is a client-specific meta-command. To make it portable, you need to split your script into one that sets up the db operating from on of the pre-existing databases (the top two lines), and another script that's meant to run already within the newly setup db (3rd line onwards). Then setup the client to open a separate session for the second script.

Comment: @Zegarek I'm asking because I need to add it to a initial script like it is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69676168/3142695

Comment: There is no need for `\c` in your sql file, you can specify both database and user directly as:   `psql -d gitea -U gitea ...`

Answer (score 0):

You created the schema in the current database (probably `postgres`), not in the one you just created. After creating the new database you need to close the connection and open a new connection to the new database. Only then can you create a schema in the new database.

Changing databases within a connection is not possible in PostgreSQL.

Comment: `Changing databases within a connection is not possible in PostgreSQL.` is not true. See [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) and [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).